# Bind forward Unknown domains

Tags: dns, bind, named

BIND must be configured so that  all of the non-existent domains redirected to internal Web server.

I tried the following configuration, failed:

```
options {
        ...
        recursion yes;
        forward first;
        forwarders { 8.8.8.8; 8.8.4.4; };
        ...
};
...
zone "."
{
    type master;
    file "/etc/named/fakezone.db";
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Such a possibility is, in the new version of BIND >= 9.9.
This config redirect all unresolved domain names to the specified address

```
zone "."
{
    type redirect;
    file "/etc/named/fakezone.db";
};
```

content file zone: **fakezone.db**

```
$TTL 300
@   IN SOA ns.example.com. admin.example.com. (
        2016020201  ; serial, todays date+todays
        86400       ; refresh, seconds
        7200        ; retry, seconds
        3600000     ; expire, seconds
        86400 )     ; minimum, seconds

@       IN NS ns.example.com.
*.      IN A 127.0.0.1
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not something that is natively supported in DNS, of any flavour.

DNS is basically the phone book of the internet, you ask it a name and it gives you a number. If you ask it a name it doesn't know it will say that it doesn't know.

The only way you could do this would be to write your own DNS resolver, so that it returns whatever you need when no answer is returned.

Comment: This isn't related to the question in any way. It is possible to do it with BIND without writing "your own DNS resolver".